# Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0 excepttion when trying to access AWS services

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, ssl, aws-sdk

Wile trying to access one of AWS services I am getting the following certificate error. I am running this on Jetty server.

I created another hello world project with the same setup it seems to work fine?

Why i'm getting the sudden - javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0 excepttion?

```
[java] software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0
 [java]     at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException$BuilderImpl.build(SdkClientException.java:97)
 [java]     at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage$RetryExecutor.handleThrownException(RetryableStage.java:136)
 [java]     at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage$RetryExecutor.execute(RetryableStage.java:94)
 [java]     at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:62)
 [java]     at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:42)
 [java]     at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
 [java]     at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:57)
 [java]     at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:37)
 [java]     at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.executeWithTimer(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:80)
 [java]     at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:60)
 [java]     at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42)
 [java]     at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
 [java]     at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
 [java]     at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:37)
 [java]     at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:26)
 [java]     at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.AmazonSyncHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonSyncHttpClient.java:240)
 [java]     at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.invoke(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:96)
 [java]     at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:120)
 [java]     at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:73)
 [java]     at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.SdkSyncClientHandler.execute(SdkSyncClientHandler.java:44)
 [java]     at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler.execute(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:55)
 [java]     at software.amazon.codeguruprofilerjavaagent.sdkclientcopy.DefaultCodeGuruProfilerClient.configureAgent(DefaultCodeGuruProfilerClient.java:137)
 [java]     at software.amazon.codeguruprofilerjavaagent.CodeGuruProfilerSDKClient.configureAgent(CodeGuruProfilerSDKClient.java:55)
 [java]     at software.amazon.codeguruprofilerjavaagent.ProfilingCommand.refreshConfiguration(ProfilingCommand.java:246)
 [java]     at software.amazon.codeguruprofilerjavaagent.ProfilingCommand.runProfiler(ProfilingCommand.java:210)
 [java]     at software.amazon.codeguruprofilerjavaagent.Timer.time(Timer.java:69)
 [java]     at software.amazon.codeguruprofilerjavaagent.ProfilingCommand.run(ProfilingCommand.java:195)
 [java]     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
 [java]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
 [java]     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
 [java]     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
 [java]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 [java]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 [java]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 [java] Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0
 [java]     at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.checkRecordVersion(InputRecord.java:552)
 [java]     at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(InputRecord.java:565)
 [java]     at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:529)
 [java]     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:975)
 [java]     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
 [java]     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
 [java]     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
 [java]     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:396)
 [java]     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:355)
 [java]     at software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.internal.conn.SdkTlsSocketFactory.connectSocket(SdkTlsSocketFactory.java:113)
 [java]     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
 [java]     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:373)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this was set in our code base, removing it solved the issue

```
System.setProperty("jsse.enableSNIExtension", "false")
```

remove the line you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. After removing this statement from the tomcat startup script it worked.
   set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false
2. Instead of removing the above statement, added below statement it worked.
   set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dhttps.protocols=SSLv3,TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2